# what is the equivalent class of Mage_Core_Block_Text_Tag_Js in magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks

what is the equivalent class of Mage_Core_Block_Text_Tag_Js in magento2?

```
class Mage_Core_Block_Text_Tag_Js extends Mage_Core_Block_Text_Tag
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTagName('script');
        $this->setTagParams(array('language'=>'javascript', 'type'=>'text/javascript'));
    }

    function setSrc($src, $type=null)
    {
        $type = (string)$type;
        if (empty($type)) {
            $type = 'js';
        }
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl($type).$src;

        return $this->setTagParam('src', $url);
    }

}
```